# Pivot column based on aggregation result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, grouping, aggregation

I have a PySpark dataframe:

| userid | sku | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2345 | 2 |
| 123 | 2345 | 0 |
| 123 | 5422 | 0 |
| 123 | 7622 | 0 |
| 231 | 4322 | 2 |
| 231 | 4322 | 0 |
| 231 | 8342 | 0 |
| 231 | 5342 | 0 |

The output should be like:

| userid | sku_pos | sku_neg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2345 | 5422 |
| 123 | 2345 | 7622 |
| 231 | 4322 | 8342 |
| 231 | 4322 | 5342 |

For each distinct "userid" the "sku" which don't have an "action" > 0 will go to column "sku_neg", while the "sku" which has an "action" > 0 will go to column "sku_pos".

Comment: So how come in your result you have two rows per `userid`?

Comment: because one sku for the userid has actiontype (0,2) and the other sku has action type only 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of aggregations is needed:

- first, assign *pos/neg* status to a "sku"
- then use this status in the 2nd aggregation to collect all "sku" into lists

Finally, explode the lists.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('123', '2345', 2),
     ('123', '2345', 0),
     ('123', '5422', 0),
     ('123', '7622', 0),
     ('231', '4322', 2),
     ('231', '4322', 0),
     ('231', '8342', 0),
     ('231', '5342', 0)],
    ['userid', 'sku', 'action'])
```

Script:

```py
df = df.groupBy('userid', 'sku').agg(
    F.when(F.max('action') > 0, 'p').otherwise('n').alias('_flag')
)
df = (df
    .groupBy('userid').pivot('_flag', ['p', 'n']).agg(F.collect_list('sku'))
    .withColumn('sku_pos', F.explode('p'))
    .withColumn('sku_neg', F.explode('n'))
    .drop('p', 'n')
)

df.show()
# +------+-------+-------+
# |userid|sku_pos|sku_neg|
# +------+-------+-------+
# |   231|   4322|   5342|
# |   231|   4322|   8342|
# |   123|   2345|   7622|
# |   123|   2345|   5422|
# +------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Create positive and negative dataframes by filtering pos/neg records and grouping by "userid":

```py
df_pos = df \
  .filter(F.col("action") > 0) \
  .groupBy("userid") \
  .agg(F.collect_set("sku").alias("sku_pos_list")) \
  .withColumnRenamed("userid", "userid_pos")

[Out]:
+----------+------------+
|userid_pos|sku_pos_list|
+----------+------------+
|       123|      [2345]|
|       231|      [4322]|
+----------+------------+


df_neg = df \
  .filter(F.col("action") <= 0) \
  .groupBy("userid") \
  .agg(F.collect_set("sku").alias("sku_neg_list")) \
  .withColumnRenamed("userid", "userid_neg")

[Out]:
+----------+------------------+
|userid_neg|      sku_neg_list|
+----------+------------------+
|       123|[2345, 5422, 7622]|
|       231|[8342, 4322, 5342]|
+----------+------------------+
```

Join back the positive and negative dataframes and explode the pos/neg records:

```py
df_joined = df_pos.join(df_neg, (F.col("userid_pos")==F.col("userid_neg")), how="full")

# Clean up null, empty
df_joined = df_joined \
  .withColumn("userid", F.when(F.col("userid_pos").isNotNull(), F.col("userid_pos")).otherwise(F.col("userid_neg"))).drop("userid_pos", "userid_neg") \
  .withColumn("sku_pos_list", F.when(F.col("sku_pos_list").isNull(), F.array([F.lit(-1)])).otherwise(F.col("sku_pos_list"))) \
  .withColumn("sku_neg_list", F.when(F.col("sku_neg_list").isNull(), F.array([F.lit(-1)])).otherwise(F.col("sku_neg_list")))

[Out]:
+------------+------------------+------+
|sku_pos_list|sku_neg_list      |userid|
+------------+------------------+------+
|[2345]      |[2345, 5422, 7622]|123   |
|[4322]      |[8342, 4322, 5342]|231   |
+------------+------------------+------+


df_joined = df_joined \
  .withColumn("sku_pos", F.explode("sku_pos_list")) \
  .withColumn("sku_neg", F.explode("sku_neg_list")) \
  .drop("sku_pos_list", "sku_neg_list") \
  .filter(F.col("sku_pos") != F.col("sku_neg"))

[Out]:
+------+-------+-------+
|userid|sku_pos|sku_neg|
+------+-------+-------+
|   123|   2345|   5422|
|   123|   2345|   7622|
|   231|   4322|   8342|
|   231|   4322|   5342|
+------+-------+-------+
```

Dataset used:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (123,2345,2),
  (123,2345,0),
  (123,5422,0),
  (123,7622,0),
  (231,4322,2),
  (231,4322,0),
  (231,8342,0),
  (231,5342,0),
], ["userid", "sku", "action"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other proposed solution seems perfectly fine but just in case, another approach that does not need a join. Note that I assume that there is only one `sku_pos` per `userid`. If that's not the case, this won't work.

```py
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("sku")\
    .withColumn("action", f.col("action") > 0)\
    .groupBy("userid", "sku")\
    .agg(f.max("action").alias("action"))\
    .groupBy("userid", "action")\
    .agg(f.collect_set("sku").alias("skus"))\
    .withColumn("sku_pos", f.col("skus").getItem(0))\
    .withColumn("sku_neg", f.when(~ f.col("action"), f.col("skus")))\
    .groupBy("userid")\
    .agg(f.first("sku_pos").alias("sku_pos"), f.first("sku_neg", ignorenulls=True).alias("sku_neg"))\
    .withColumn("sku_neg", f.explode("sku_neg"))\
    .show()\
+------+-------+-------+
|userid|sku_pos|sku_neg|
+------+-------+-------+
|   123|   5422|   5422|
|   123|   5422|   7622|
|   231|   4322|   5342|
|   231|   4322|   8342|
+------+-------+-------+
```

Basically the idea is first to use a `groupBy` to collect the positive and negative `sku` separately. Then I use `f.col("skus").getItem(0)` to only select one `sku_pos`, use another `groupBy` to have one line per `userid` and finally explode the `sku_neg` array.